# Looking for help speeding up a count distinct query on a large mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been searching on ways to optimize my count distinct query for a while now with no success. It seems to me like there should be some simple solution, but I just haven't found it.

I have 1 table that has a large amount of records in it. It currently has about 500 000 records and it will eventually be in the millions.

I am currently trying to display the distinct count of 3 fields in real-time, but my count distinct query is very slow, so my results are "lagged" behind the real count.

The queries I have found online and have been using are:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct c1, c2 from table
where c3 >= '2018-04-05 00:00:00') as count;

select count(distinct c1, c2) from table where c3 >= '2018-04-05 00:00:00';
```

Each of these queries task ~3 seconds to run, but I need it to be as fast as possible.

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Cheers.

EDIT: It is worth noting that I have indexed the columns already, but it only shaved ~1 second off the query.

Here are the outputs for the explains:

```
 id select_type table      partitions type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows   filtered Extra           
 -- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---- ------------- ---- ------- ---- ------ -------- --------------- 
  1 PRIMARY     <derived2> NULL       ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 503560    100.0 NULL           
  2 DERIVED     TABLE      NULL       ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 503560    100.0 Using temporary


 id select_type table     partitions type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows   filtered Extra 
-- ----------- --------- ---------- ---- ------------- ---- ------- ---- ------ -------- ----- 
 1 SIMPLE      TABLE      NULL       ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 503562    100.0 NULL
```

Comment: Both queries should run faster with the index `(c3, c1, c2)`

Comment: "EDIT: It is worth noting that I have indexed the columns already, but it only shaved ~1 second off the query." Show the outputs off `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` and a `EXPLAIN [query]` of both queries

Comment: I already have that index on the table, I mistakenly left it out of the original post, but I have since edited it. Thanks though.

Comment: I have added the outputs for the queries respectively.

Comment: End the show create table? Because the explain tells me there are no possible keys

Comment: Could it be because neither of those fields are keys in my table? My table is quite large. It contains 24 fields and neither of these are primary keys. They are just other fields I want to query on.

Answer (score 0):

Try group by instead of distinct. Distinct is costly when you have large number of records, because DB sorts the result set before finding count.

```
select count(*) from (select c1, c2 from table group by c1,c2
where c3 >= '2018-04-05 00:00:00') as count;
```

Comment: "Distinct is costly when you have large number of records, because DB sorts the result set before finding count." GROUP BY in MySQL has a automatic ORDER BY... DISTINCT doesn't have that.. So you answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I had already given this a try and it is almost twice as slow.

Comment: @RaymondNijland:- Can you cite MySQL documentation and share the link if you have already.

Comment: GROUP BY "However, you still have some control over sort order. GROUP BY in MySQL implicitly sorts results by default (in the absence of ASC or DESC designators). However, implicit GROUP BY sorting in MySQL is deprecated. To achieve a specific sort order of grouped results: " -> source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html ..